# What is the cause for the error message `SSHConnectionAborted` using Net::SSH::Expect?

Tags: perl, module, ssh

While connecting to the remote host using the [`Net::SSH::Expect` module](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aExpect), 2 out of 10 times I get the error `SSHConnectionAborted`.

I an unable to find the reason for this error and its solution. Can anybody please help me in this?

I am using the following Perl code:

```
my $Ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
    host       => 15.178.209.112,
    user       => Administrator,
    password   => Password,
    raw_pty    => 1,
    timeout    => 10,
    log_stdout => 1
);
eval {$Ssh_Login = $Ssh->login();};
```

Comment: why on earth did you tag this `html`?

Comment: That's some pretty fancy looking HTML.

Comment: see i dont know about tagging. its a perl code and i want help

Comment: @Nitesh please leave the networking tag, and mind you, calm down a bit

Comment: very new to stack overflow. sory. can u help me how to raise a question again as it is a perl code

Comment: @Nitesh it should be fine now. and just wait. not everything happens within the first ten minutes; sometimes questions take days to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use [Net::SSH::Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aExpect), it is just not reliable!

[Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH2), [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) (does not work on Cygwin or Windows) or even [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl) are better options.

**Update**: If all of those fail, [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect) may still be a good option.

Comment: we are using cygwin environment to execute our scripts. Do u think these modules are suitable for cygwin.

Comment: What are the possible issues related with Net::SSH::Expect module

Comment: @Nitesh: I do not use Cygwin myself so I don't know for sure but Net::SSH2 is probably your best option there. The problem with Net::SSH::Expect is that it relies exclusively on timeouts to determine when some command or operation has finished.

Comment: Thanks salva for your help. I will try my script with Net::SSH2 module. Thanks a lot